# I need to check if a pointer points to a math.h function

Tags: c

Is there any way I can check if a pointer points to a string that is sin, cos, pow, log or exp that are part of the math.h header file?

I need to implement the following pseudo code:

```
if(ptr is equal to sin,cos,log,exp,pow)
  Execute code
else
  return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe more extreme than you are looking for but if you load the library with `dlopen` you could then lookup a symbol with `dlsym`.

Comment: `if (ptr == &sin || ptr == &cos ...)`? But can you please tell us *why* you want to do this? What is the *original* problem that you want to solve? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Is the pointer a string "sin", "cos" or a function pointer sin, cos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can check if a pointer points to a string that is
>   sin, cos, pow, log or exp that are part of the math.h header file?

I assume you would like to call different *math* functions based on a string match.

You could use something like following data structure to achieve this:

```
// Make a generic function pointer, since no. of arguments differs
typedef double (*genericfptr)( );

struct FunMap
{
    const char* funName;
    genericfptr fptr;
    unsigned int nargs;
};

// Following could be used to get correct compatible types
typedef double (*OneArg)( double );
typedef double (*TwoArg)( double , double );
```

---

Then you could create a data structure to map nfunctions and no. of arguments like :

```
struct FunMap fMap[ ] = 
{
    { "sin", sin, 1 },
    { "cos", cos, 1 },
    { "log", log, 1 },
    { "pow", pow, 2 },
    // ....
};
```

---

Using this *function* map table you can call function based on our *string match*.  Something like following :

```
    if( strcmp( p, fMap[ j ].funName ) == 0 )
    {

        switch( fMap[ j ].nargs )
        {
            case 1:
            result = ((OneArg )fMap[ j ].fptr)( val1 );
            break;

            case 2:

            result = ((TwoArg )fMap[ j ].fptr)( val1, val2 );
            break;

            default:
            result = 0.0;
            //assert ( false );
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

<kbd>[***`Demo here`***](http://rextester.com/ESZH39232)</kbd>